# How to Improve performance with recursion code

Tags: excel, vba

In the Below code, I use recursion to get list of all files under all folders and subfolders starting from a specific path, The issue i'm having is... Once this code is run, Excel would go into "Not Responding" State until the code is done.

is there a way... even if it takes longer for the code to finish but to have it run without interruption to excel? I have already tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but it's not helping...

```
Dim r As Integer

Private Sub Test()

r = 1
GetFilesInFolder "C:\Users\xxx\Documents", True

End Sub

Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)

Dim FSO
Dim SourceFolder, SubFolder
Dim FileItem

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

'--- Display File Name, Path, And Extension In specified cells...

Dim Ext As String
For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
    Ext = VBA.Right(FileItem.Name, VBA.Len(FileItem.Name) - VBA.InStrRev(FileItem.Name, "."))
    Cells(r, 1).Formula = FileItem.Name
    Cells(r, 2).Formula = FileItem.Path
    Cells(r, 3).Formula = Ext
    r = r + 1   ' next row number
Next FileItem

'--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files.

If Subfolders = True Then
    For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
        GetFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
    Next SubFolder
End If

Set FileItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to move around the worksheet while the code is running? :-)

Comment: Note that VBA cannot multi-thread. That means VBA code cannot run simultanously and you have to wait for it. • Side note: instead of the 3 `.Formula` you should use `.Value` if you write values and no formulas (what you actually do). And `Dim r As Long` Excel has more rows than `Integer` could handle.

Comment: Rather than writing to the worksheet for every file that you find, write to an array, and then dump the contents of the array to the worksheet at the end.

Comment: If your code has no issues (running without errors) and your question is only about performance, this question should be better asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Peh, My issue is mentioned in OP: "The issue i'm having is... Once this code is run, Excel would go into "Not Responding" State"

Comment: Hi Applecore, Can you give me an example of this? i'm new to VBA and from what i know you cannot keep adding items to array

Comment: That is no issue. That is because the code is still running and you have to wait until it is finished (VBA cannot multi-thread so Excel does not respond until it finished). That is a normal behavior! For how using arrays see here: [Reading from a Range to the VBA Array](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_to_the_VBA_Array)

Comment: Hi Peh and All, I added "DoEvents" below line "r = r + 1" and it seems to have improved performance (not getting no response) by alot, i'm not 100% sure of what it does excatly

Comment: `DoEvents` will not improve performance, instead it will get worse. It stops your code at the line `DoEvents` (because it does not support multi-threading) and allows Excel to perform other events. If Excel is finished with the events, your code will proceed. While this looks like "better" it is actually worse now, because in total your code needs longer to finish. Note that any action you perform while `DoEvents` can easily mess with your (still not finished) code. I highly recommend not to do that.

Comment: I See, so there is no "Good" way to have the code running in background without disrupting the user activity in excel? for longer loops it excel will stop for more than 2 minutes... very annoying

Comment: @AliAlnuaimi No, actually not, because of lacking multi-thread support VBA cannot be run in background. There is only the option to wait for it to finish or pause it with `DoEvents` to perform events (not that these events can interfere with your code) and will definitely slow it down.

Comment: @AliAlnuaimi - Did you also turn off calculations?

Comment: @AliAlnuaimi Check out my answer below. Using arrays would possibly give the biggest performance boost. Deactivating screen updating or calculations is not necessary then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following code could give you a performance boost:

1. Create FSO only once (not every recursion) will save some time.
2. Using an array to collect the file data first will be much faster. Note that each read/write action to a cell takes a huge amount of time. Here we have only one write action in the very end, where we write the whole array data **at once**.

Note that due to the fact that resizing a multi-dimensional array

```
ReDim Preserve OutputArr(1 To 3, 1 To c)
```

only can resize the last dimension we needed to swap columns and rows in the array. To still have the same output as before we transpose the complete array in the end when writing it to the cells.

---

```
Option Explicit

Dim c As Long
Dim OutputArr() As Variant
Dim FSO As Object

Private Sub Test()
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    c = 1 'initialize
    
    'define array size
    ReDim OutputArr(1 To 3, 1 To 1)
    'note the array is columns/rows switched because we can only resize the second dimension
    'to put it correctly in rows/columns we use Transpose later
    
    GetFilesInFolder "C:\Temp", True
    Set FSO = Nothing
    
    'write the array into the cells
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(OutputArr, 2), UBound(OutputArr, 1)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(OutputArr)
End Sub

Public Sub GetFilesInFolder(ByVal SourceFolderName As String, ByVal Subfolders As Boolean)
    Dim SourceFolder As Object, SubFolder As Variant
    Dim FileItem As Variant
    
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)
    
    '--- Display File Name, Path, And Extension In specified cells...
    
    Dim Ext As String
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Ext = VBA.Right$(FileItem.Name, VBA.Len(FileItem.Name) - VBA.InStrRev(FileItem.Name, "."))
        'here we work only with the array to lower read/write actions to the cells
        OutputArr(1, c) = FileItem.Name
        OutputArr(2, c) = FileItem.Path
        OutputArr(3, c) = Ext
        c = c + 1
        ReDim Preserve OutputArr(1 To 3, 1 To c) 'resize array
    Next FileItem
    
    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files.
    
    If Subfolders = True Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
            GetFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If
    
    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

As Applecore mentioned in the comments below: Some small extra boost could be reached by defining a bigger array in the beginning (like 1000)

```
ReDim OutputArr(1 To 3, 1 To 1000)
```

and later only resize if this limit of 1000 was reached

```
If c > 1000 Then ReDim Preserve OutputArr(1 To 3, 1 To c)
```

and finally limit the write to cell action to `c - 1` then:

```
Range("A1").Resize(c - 1, UBound(OutputArr, 1)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(OutputArr)
```

Comment: Rather than redimensioning the array each loop, it would be slightly faster to initialise it with a large upper limit (say 1000), and then only resize it when needed.

Comment: @Applecore right, this could give some little extra speed, but the mayority of the boost here will come from reducing read/write actions to the cells to only 1.

Comment: Every little helps!! Also, using `Mid(Output(1,c), InStrRev(Output(1,c),".")+1)` might give a slight boost - only two functions used, and possibly not using `FileItem.Name` is faster. But, these boosts would be minimal unless the number of iterations is very large.....